# How to unittest "new style" Django middleware

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-middleware, django-tests

I am learning how to unittest Django middleware.

In the 'old style' Middleware, it was easy enough to load middleware using `process_request()` to test results. E.g.

```
def test_session(self):
    request = self.factory.get('/')
    session_middleware = SessionMiddleware()
    session_middleware.process_request(request)
    // Do stuff
```

However, in the 'new style' this does not exist. For example, how would I test the following example [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone) provide?

```
class TimezoneMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        tzname = request.session.get('django_timezone')
        if tzname:
            timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(tzname))
        else:
            timezone.deactivate()
        return self.get_response(request)
```

Using `TimezoneMiddleware(request)` will call the `__init__` but not the `__call__`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see, the middleware simply implements a `__call__` magic method. This means the instance of this class is *callable*.

The difference between the old-style and new-style middleware is that the new middleware is simply a callable that returns a callable - first you call it with a `get_response` callback, and then you call the returned callable with the actual request. `get_response` is a callable provided/injected by Django itself, and it's a function used to either return the view response, or the next middleware in the chain.

So, in order to test your `SessionMiddleware`, you could do the following:

```
import mock

def test_middleware(self):
    get_response = mock.MagicMock()
    request = self.factory.get('/')

    middleware = SessionMiddleware(get_response)
    response = middleware(request)

    # ensure get_response has been returned 
    # (or not, if your middleware does something else)
    self.assertEqual(get_response.return_value, response)
```

Comment: Thanks, this returns `response = middleware(request)` with `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'session'` ?

Comment: What middleware are you testing? Because `SessionMiddleware` is the one that attaches the session object to the request: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py#L24 - if you're testing another middleware that depends on the session middleware, you have to either use session middleware first or mock the `.session` attribute on the request.

Comment: I'm testing the `TimezoneMiddleware` shown in the question, which requires a session?

Comment: Yes, you can see it in this line: `tzname = request.session.get('django_timezone')` - it requires a session to be attached to the request beforehand.