# How to pass request field into Django test?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, request

I have a function:

```py
def test_function(request):
    return request.device.id
```

which connected to endpoint `/test_end/`

I need to write a unittest but not working -> request.device is None

Test looks like this:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client


class Device:
    def __int__(self, _id):
        self.id = _id


class MyTest(TestCase):
    
    def test_device(self):
        client = Client()
        response = client.get("/test_end", device=Device(42))
```

How to fix it?

I need to pass device to function into request

Answer (score 1):

Try using RequestFactory to generate a request and then you can call the view directly like `test_function(request)`

For example :

```
from django.test import RequestFactory
request = self.factory.get('/test_end')
request.device = device() # here replace with the Device object 
response = test_function(request)
print(response)
```

Comment: It's worked, but I need to send a request to endpoint, for checking middleware.

Comment: Ok. Why couldn't you check Middleware seperately like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944755/how-to-unittest-new-style-django-middleware ?